# Piecewise polynomial order and knot number+position optimization for a given maximum error

Tags: python, curve-fitting, spline, polynomials, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to approximate a digital filter impulse response with a set of piecewise polynomials:

1. The number of segment(knot) is a free parameter on the entire interval [0,1). To give perspective of the problem size, I'm expecting something like 256 to 1024 segments for a good approximation.
2. The knot positions have to fall on a power of 2 integer grid on the interval [0,1] for easy hardware implementation of the polynomial selection.
3. The polynomial order for each segment can be different, the lower the better. The maximum order is known (could be set to 2, or 3).
4. The length of each segment does not need to be equal as long as (2) is obeyed.

For example a linear segment on [0, 1/256) followed by a 3rd order segment on [1/256, 22/256) followed by a 2nd order segment on [22/256, 1) would be fine.

The goal is to minimize some kind of combination of the number of segments and their order to reduce overall computation/memory cost (tradeoff to be defined), while the mean square or maximum error between fitted curve and ideal is below a given value.

I know I could brute force search the entire space and calculate the max error for each allowed polynomial order, for each allowed segment. I could then 'construct' the final piecewise curve by walking through this large table - although I'm not entirely sure how to exactly do the final construct.

I'm wondering if this is not a 'known' type of problem for which algorithms already exist. Any comments welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can try a variant of the [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm). It's an easy-to-implement algorithm for simplifying polygonal lines. In your context, the polygonal line is a sample of your filter curve at the grid points and the algorithm certifies that the maximal error is smaller than some threshold.

If you need a smooth curve you can modify the algorithm to implement a quadratic spline interpolation instead of a polyline approximation (which correspond to a linear spline interpolation) and similarly a cubic spline for second order continuity. In each iteration the farthest sample point is added to the interpolation point set and the interpolation spline is re-computed.

A slightly different alternative is to use a [least-square approximating spline](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/CURVE-APP-global.html) instead of an interpolation spline. A new **knot** will be added in each iteration at the grid point with farthest distance but the curve will not be required to pass through it.

This approach, while simple, answers most of your requirements and gives good results in practice.
However, it may not give the theoretical optimal solution (although I don't currently have a counter example).